# Load controller without $route

Tags: codeigniter

exmple: this load default controller/class with function `page`,

```
www.example.com/page
```

unless we have controller/class named `page` AND set `$route['page'] = 'page';` it'll load the controller. But if we dont set the `$route`, it'll still load default_controller.

is that true a `controller` must have a `$route['']` always? is not it possible to load controller `page` without set `$route['']` **even there is no default controller function with same name?**

**Edit:**

I access

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/user
```

I do have `user` controller with `index` function, but my route file only contain:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/$1';
$route['product'] = 'product';
//$route['user'] = 'user';
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

returns `404`, only works if I uncomment this: `$route['user'] = 'user';`

why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not true. CodeIgniter, by default, [directly maps URI segments](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) to:

```
example.com/index.php/controller/method/param/param/...
```

Or if you have an .htaccess / similar solution to remove index.php:

```
example.com/controller/method/param/param/...
```

[Routing](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) is used when you wish to use a URL that does not directly map to this convention.

**Edit**: You have conflicting routes. CodeIgniter will look at each route in order from top to bottom, and if it find one that matches, it stops looking and processes that route. Because you have an `(:any)` catch-all route, it will match *anything* (like it says).

The rule of thumb is to place your most specific routes first, and then get more generic and catch-all later. Your `(:any)` route should be the very last one in your list. And the default controller and 404 overrides should stay first.

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['404_override'] = '';

$route['product'] = 'product';
$route['user'] = 'user';
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/$1';
```

You need to add the `product` and `user` routes because you've defined the `(:any)` route. If you want to avoid writing route rules for every one of your existing controllers, but still take advantage of a catch-all controller, consider using the `404_override` controller/method instead. You can do your verifications to check if the URI is valid there. Just make sure to throw a 404 error if not (you can use `show_404()`), since any non-existant URL will be routed to there.

Comment: You have conflicting routes that require defining each existing controller.