# Codeigniter is running without route?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I downloaded the CodeIgniter version of 2.2.6. I made configuration on config.php. Everything is normal up to now :) After I added  another controller into my project. And boom :) It worked without any route condition. Futhermore, When I removed all routes file, it was still working.

How could it be possible? is there any answer about this?

I thought it was about my .htaccess file. But I am already using the same htaccess file in another project, in which I have to use route.

Here is my .htacess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Thanks for your answers.
Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load controller without $route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756315/load-controller-without-route)

Comment: Reading the documentation should be of help. Hint: something to do with wild cards in routes file

Answer (score 1):

if you use url segment is correct. It wont show error it call the class and its function no need to create a route for that. For example

```
domainName.com/myClass/firstFunction
```

from above code my class name is `myClass` so it call the class if the class exist then it goes to the function that is `firstFunction` and execute that function.

If you want to hide the class name and function name then the route helps in this case

```
domainName.com/home/homeFunction
```

And my route as follows

```
$route['home/homeFunction'] = 'myClass/firstFunction';
```

I hope you understand this... If you still have doubt on this I'm happy to guide you...

Comment: Good... Keep developing... @GokhanKandemir

Answer (score 1):

Routes is only for your CI application to direct the browser to a particular function from a class, which is to be called when, user enters the specified URL. `http://localhost/mySite/myURL`

If you are referring to the function by addressing both the class and function in the URL itself `http://localhost/mySite/myClass/myFunction` , then the CI app delivers the right content to your browser without even going to the routes.

Routes are generally used to give meaningful names to your URLs to make it more user friendly, and also increases SEO.

`$route['contact'] = 'myClass/myFunction';`

Now, you can simply refer to the function as

`http://localhost/mySite/contact`

I Hope it helped in better understanding more about Routes.